# How do I make my HTML and java form redirect to itself so that the user can input another item?

Tags: java, html, servlets, form-submit

I am not even sure if I should use redirect. 
What I have is a form (html) that uses java to read the input when the submit button is pressed and that part works fine. What I want is to be able to enter another item in the same form and submit this new item the same way. I am using a Java servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have 2 options. The first one is to put a redirect script on the page that appears after the form is submitted to redirect the user to the previous page. It should be something like:

```
<html>
    ...
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="5;URL=PreviousPageURL">
    <body>
        You have successfully created an item! <br/>
        You will be redirected to the previous page to create more items after 5s.
    </body>
    ...
</html>
```

Another way is to use Ajax to submit your form instead. Try this jQuery plugin [ajaxForm](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/):

```
<form id="myForm">
    ...
</form>
<div id="status"></div> // Show the result here

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myForm').ajaxForm({ 
        beforeSubmit: function() {
            $("#status").html("");
        },
        success: function(response){
            var status = $(response).find("status").text();
            $("#status").html(status);
        },
        dataType: "xml"
    });
</script>
```

In the above example, I return the result as an xml file like this:

```
<status>Successful/Failed/etc.</status>
```

You can also return the result as a string.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried the first suggestion and it works, I will try the rest as well.

Comment: Or redirect back to the JSP from the servlet the form is submitted to, which seems the most obvious non-Ajax solution.